# How can I make an UILabel appear and disappear 5 times?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

When I press a button, a view with a label appears. Then I want the label to disappear and reappear 5 times (with animation), each time the label reappears with different text.
I can't seem to get the any code to work to animate a UILabel and change the text. I have tried this. However, when I press the button, the loop and animations occur instantly.

The duration is a follows: 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5

```
for i in 1...5 {

            infoViewMsgLbl.text = randomReward(real: i) // This retrives a String

            UIView.animate(withDuration: ((1.5/5)*Double(i)), delay: 0.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: { 
                self.infoViewMsgLbl.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { finished in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: ((1.5/5)*Double(i)), animations: { 
                    self.infoViewMsgLbl.alpha = 1
                })
            })

            print("in the loop: ", i)
        }
```

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code and clearly explain what issues you are having with the code.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing `duration`, but leaving `delay` as `0` (i.e. start immediately). In these cases, you might do it the other way around, changing `delay` and leaving `duration` unchanged.

But given that you want to change the label `text`, I might use a timer instead:

```
var index = 1
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
    self?.infoViewMsgLbl.alpha = 0
    self?.infoViewMsgLbl.text = self?.randomReward(real: index)
    index += 1
    if index > 5 { timer.invalidate() }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self?.infoViewMsgLbl.alpha = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, didn't think of using a timer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
func animate(alpha: CGFloat, start: Int, end: Int) {

    infoViewMsgLbl.text = randomReward(real: Int(start/2)) // This retrives a String

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.infoViewMsgLbl.alpha = alpha
    }, completion: { success in

        if start + 1 <= end {
            self.animate(alpha: alpha == 1.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0, start: start + 1, end: end)
        }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
animate(alpha:0.0, start: 0, end: 10)  //would flash a total of 5 times
```

Note that the duration stays 0.3 because it doesn't call the next loop until each additional 0.3 seconds has passed.

Comment: The function works. However, it leaves the label with an alpha = 0 when it finishes.

Comment: You could run it 11 times.  But I agree that Rob's timer implementation is probably a better way to solve this anyhow.